# Blob constructor not working in safari / opera?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to construct a Blob from an array buffer that original comes from a binary string. It works fine in Firefox & Chrome, but I don't know whats wrong with Safari & Opera

This is a simplified version of my problem: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/sfEEHf?p=preview

```
// 1x1 red PNG pixle
base64 = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQIW2P8z8DwHwAFBQIAHl6u2QAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
byteString = atob(base64);

// convert binary to array buff so we can construct a blob later
arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
intArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

for (i = 0; i < byteString.length; i += 1) {
  intArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}

// construct blob
blob = new Blob([intArray], {type: "image/png"});
console.log(blob.size); // suppose to be 70 (its 19 in safari)
```

Comment: The used methods are supported only by FF/Chrome/IE10, take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/DataView#Browser_compatibility for the compatibility-list

Comment: You know any workaround? Working with typed array is kind of new to me... just want to go from a binary string to a blob

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Safari you need to use the 'buffer' property on the TypedArray, i.e. this:

```
blob = new Blob([intArray.buffer], {type: "image/png"});
```

and it'll work.

Comment: What if your view is a slice of a buffer?

Comment: Does not work for me ... I am using it without the second parameter {type: "image/png"}

Comment: Doesn't worked for me also. I'm using safari browser 5.1.7 and using same blob example mentioned above.