# Safari - init image from Blob w/ CORS - always getting error

Tags: javascript, html, safari, blob, cors

Flow:

1. use XHR with CORS in order to get image file as Blob
2. Create Blob object from the response
3. up to now - all OK
4. using createObjectURL in order to initialize Image object
5. the "onload" event never fires, the "onerror" event ALWAYS fires error.

example:

```
var blob = new Blob(...);
var img = document.createElement('img');

img.onload = function (e1) {
                //do something after image loaded
            };

img.onerror = function(e2) {
       alert('Error!');
       //always fires on Safari
};

img.src = my_createObjectURL(blob);
document.body.appendChild(img);


function my_createObjectURL(blob) {
    if (window.webkitURL) {
        return window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }
    else if (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL) {
        return window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Firefox, Chrome & IE10 -- working correctly, no errors

Tested on Safari 6.0.5 -- never get onload, always getting onerror event

Comment: Have you tried addEventListener('load', function() { }); ?

Comment: have you checked this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347534/blob-constructor-not-working-in-safari-opera ?

Comment: Yes. The Blob object created successfully.
It's just that when the Image is initialized with a Blob, it always fires the "error" event ...