# Safari browsers sends blob/datauri as string in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, data-url

I am trying to receive the file sent through AJAX. What's happening is that when the file sent using Chrome/Firefox the file goes to `req.files` but when it was sent using Safari, the file goes to `req.params`. The application treat the file as a string "[Object blob]". Thanks.

Sending userdata through ajax.

```
updatePartnerProfile: function(obj){
      var parentObj = this;
      var target = $(obj.target);
      var parent = target.closest('#editPartnerDetailsForm');
      var logoImg = parent.find('.cropped');
      var companyLogoBase64 = logoImg.find('.croppedImage').attr('src');
      var companyLogo = util.dataURItoBlob(companyLogoBase64);

      var userData = new FormData();
      userData.append('token', parentObj.token);
      userData.append('companyLogo', companyLogo);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: parentObj.serverUrl + 'api/admin/update/organization/' + parentObj.partnerId,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: userData,
        success: function(data){
          //todo
          }
        },
        error: function(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    },

dataURItoBlob : function(dataURI) {
  // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
  if (!_.isUndefined(dataURI)){
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
      byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
      byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
      // separate out the mime component
      var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
      // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
      var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Am I missing something in the code?

Comment: post your browser code so we can see what you're doing wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX Already updated my post. Thanks for a quick response

Answer (score 0):

Well, [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347534/blob-constructor-not-working-in-safari-opera), you need to be using the `buffer` property of `ia`, not just `[ia]`.  Instead of

```
return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
```

try

```
return new Blob([ia.buffer], {type:mimeString});
```