# Error [object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor in safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, blob

I am getting this error in safari in windows 7 in this section

```
'[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'})')
```

And After using solution of [Blob constructor not working in safari / opera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347534/blob-constructor-not-working-in-safari-opera)

```
'[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Blob([data.buffer], {type: 'application/pdf'})')
```

I am using this `Blob` code

```
var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

Complete code is

```
      $scope.pdffile = "";
      $http.get('/api/myurl/'+report_id, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
         .success(function (data) {
             var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
             var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
             $scope.pdfcontent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
             $scope.pdffile = "download.pdf";
             $scope.loading = false;
      });
```

Comment: Any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple [drops Windows support](http://appleinsider.com/articles/12/07/25/apple_kills_windows_pc_support_in_safari_60) for Safari 6 back in 2012.

So apparently You are using version 5 which [does not supports](http://caniuse.com/#search=Blob) Blob API.